# Include code from an external R script, run in, display both code and output

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Is it possible to include code from an external R script in an .Rmd and simultaneously run the code, display the code, and display its results in the output .HTML file? For example, if I have

```
x <- 1
y <- 3
z <- x + y
z
```

in `external.R`. In the output document I want to see the code above along with the result of `z`, i.e. 4. Essentially, I want the equivalent of what would happen if I copy/pasted what's above in an R chunk. So I want

````
```{r}
some.library::some.function("external.R")
```
````

to be the equivalent of

````
```{r}
x <- 1
y <- 3
z <- x + y
z
```
````

In the output HTML file.
I've tried things like `knitr::read_chunk('external.R)` and `source('external.R`)`, but these don't display the code. Am I missing something simple?

---

**EDIT**

I found that `source('external.R', echo = TRUE)` will produce what I ask, but each line of the output's displayed code/results is prepended by `##`. Any way to make it look like it would if the code was simply copy/pasted in a chunk in the .Rmd?

Comment: I guess my first question is: Why? What are you trying to do? Secondly, if I do `source("my_script.R", echo = T)` I don't see any code/results prefixed by `##`. It looks exactly how it would look if I were to copy&paste code into an R terminal. Perhaps I misunderstood?

Comment: We'll, I'm not comparing the result to what it would look like in  in an R terminal. I'm comparing it to how it looks in an output .HTML file.

Comment: I'm giving my students an assignment where they have to complete several lengthy tasks, and for organizational purposes, I think it's easier to use external scripts rather than put everything in multiple code chunks. Also, if they execute code line-by-line in a code chunk in a .Rmd, Rstudio puts the output in a "drawer" under the chunk, which is annoying to me, as I think it makes more sense for it to appear in the console like it does in a simple .R file.

Comment: I'm not quite following. You seem to be mixing up RMarkdown and straight-up R files. If you don't like the way RMarkdown renders code&text, don't use RMarkdown. But then you are saying that you are "*not comparing the result to what it would look like in in an R terminal.*" So what are you actually trying to do and how are you executing code? In a R terminal? In RStudio? Is code in an RMarkdown file? Or in an R script. I've had my students very successfully use RMarkdown and R Notebooks. In my opinion it encourages transparent code documentation and consistent coding standards.

Comment: I love the way Rmarkdown renders code and text. What I'm saying is that if I use `source('external.R', echo = T)`, the output HTML file has `##` in front of each line. If I were to simply copy/paste the contents of my external R code into a code chunk in the .Rmd, it renders without the `##`. Does that make sense? My comment about the result is the terminal was in reference to your first comment about what the result looks like in an R terminal. I don't really care about that - I only care about how it looks in the output HTML file.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. I've posted an potential option below, please take a look if that does what you're after.

Comment: Try this to stop ## at beginning of output lines 
knitr::opts_knit$set(progress = FALSE, verbose = FALSE)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Although the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52398016/2706569) provides a simple and working solution, I think the most idiomatic way of doing this (without having to modify the external script at all) is to use the [chunk option `code`](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#code-chunk) to set the contents of `external.R` as chunk code:

````
```{r, code = readLines("external.R")}
```
````

Comment: Even better. GOSH I changed the accepted answer twice. I ought to wait a day or two before selecting one.

Comment: I think this one will be the definitive answer (the rest two are also correct answers). What a coincidence -- I just wrote about the `code` option yesterday: https://yihui.name/en/2018/09/code-appendix/

Comment: how do i call an external script without showing the external code?  For example, setting API keys ?

Answer (score 16):

There is another way of doing it so it looks **exactly** like having the code in the markdown file.

Your `external.R` file:

```
## @knitr answer
x <- 1
y <- 3
z <- x + y
z
```

Your Rmarkdown file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
knitr::read_chunk('external.R')
```

```{r}
<<answer>>
```
````

That produces:
[image]

Comment: Yep. Good call. This isn't exactly what I requested in my question, but as it turns out, this it is what I was looking for.

Comment: This works for me but in RStudio, the editor indicates the line with `<<answer>>` is an `unexpected token '<' error`. I didn't know you could use info like `@knitr`.

Comment: FYI, the error RStudio was giving me appears to have gone away.

Answer (score 11):

You could set `comment = NA` in your code chunk options.

Example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = TRUE,
    comment=NA)
```

## Example

```{r}
source("example.R", echo = T, prompt.echo = "", spaced = F)
```
````

This produces

[image]

Comment: I think at last, Mr. Baggins, you and I understand one another. That does the trick. Thanks Maurits.

Comment: No worries @haff;-) Glad it was helpful.

Comment: Ok, I hate to go back on what I said, but this doesn't exactly produce what I want. It's almost there, but maybe `source` isn't the right function. In the example you have above, the lines `x <- 3` and `y <- 4` don't have syntax highlighting. These lines are prepended with a `>` (like they were run in the R shell), which I think this is probably an artifact of how the `source` function works?

Comment: @haff No problem at all. Everything makes a lot more sense now that I understand what you are trying to do. You can change the prompt character with `prompt.echo` within `source`. So for example, `source("example.R", echo = T, prompt.echo = "")` would remove the `>`. You can also remove the additional extra  linebreak with  `source("example.R", echo = T, prompt.echo = "", spaced = F)`. Does that help?

Comment: Yes - that's good to know. I think spadarian's answer captures what I wanted to do a bit better, but I can foresee of other cases in which the source options you listed will be helpful to me. Thanks.

Comment: You're very welcome @haff. I didn't know about `knitr::read_chunk`, happy to have learned something new.