# Include a function from external source R in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Suppose I have a `functions.R` script in which I have defined a few functions:

```r
foo <- function(x) print(x-2)
bar <- function(x) print(x^3)
...
```

Now I want to include **only** `foo` (and **not the whole** `functions.R` in a chunk in RMarkdown.

If I wanted all functions to be included, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52400206/2275986), I could have done this via:

````
``` {r, code = readLines("functions.R")}
```
````

However, I only need `foo` in the chunk. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know what lines the functions you want are on, you could follow the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12215731/8386140)

Comment: Thanks @duckmayr, I didn't know I could do that. However I'm a bit reluctant to do it that way since there might be changes to the scripts (adding/removing few lines somewhere) and that'll screw things up.

Comment: Sure, would definitely be a very fragile approach; adding a more robust approach now

Answer (score 3):

I adapt the approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26620837/8386140) to a related question to solve this problem.<sup>1</sup>

I stored in the file `functions.R` your two example functions above:

```
foo <- function(x) print(x-2)
bar <- function(x) print(x^3)
```

I then create the following R Markdown document:

````
---
title: "SO Answer"
author: "duckmayr"
date: "7/8/2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

We set up a function to source an R script, but only assign to the global environment the functions we want:

```{r source_function}
source_functions <- function(fcn_names, file_name) {
    env <- new.env()
    source(file_name, local = env)
    for ( i in 1:length(fcn_names) ) {
        assign(fcn_names[i], get(fcn_names[i], envir = env), envir = .GlobalEnv)
    }
}
```

Then we can call it to get *only* the function `foo()`:

```{r get_foo}
source_functions("foo", "functions.R")
ls()
```

This will also work for multiple functions:

```{r get_foo_and_bar}
source_functions(c("foo", "bar"), "functions.R")
ls()
```
````

Which renders as:

[image]

We see that in the first call to `source_functions()`, only the `foo()` function is added to the global environment, but *not* the `bar()` function, which should work to solve your problem. If you wanted multiple functions from `functions.R`, this will also work as well, as demonstrated in the second call to `source_functions()`.

### Update: Showing the Functions' Code

We can edit our `source_functions()` function to show the code of the functions it sources, like so:

```
source_functions <- function(fcn_names, file_name) {
    env <- new.env()
    source(file_name, local = env)
    n <- length(fcn_names)
    result <- character(n)
    for ( i in 1:n ) {
        name <- fcn_names[i]
        fcn <- get(name, envir = env)
        code <- capture.output(show(fcn))
        code <- paste(code[-which(grepl("<env", code))], collapse = " ")
        assign(name, fcn, envir = .GlobalEnv)
        result[i] <- paste(name, "<-", code, collapse = " ")
    }
    return(result)
}
```

Then our document renders as

[image]

---

1 <sub>That question and answer (1) was not in the context of R Markdown, and more importantly (2) only demonstrated how to get **all** functions from an R script (without getting other objects) rather than *particular* functions.</sub>

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way, like with another function, include the raw code of the function in the output? (like a code written in the chunk, as `code = readLines("functions.R")` in the chunk definition does for the whole script.)

Comment: @ManuelHaqi Sure, easily. The answer is updated to include that functionality

Comment: Thanks again @duckmayr. I actually meant it a bit differently: I want the function `echo`ed as a piece of code in the output. I have shown it in this [image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8527082/60826981-a106e880-a19e-11e9-85ac-2205d286bccc.png). Your updated solution gives A, but B (or C) is what I mean.

Comment: Ah, I see... that I think would be more difficult. If I have time later I'll see if I can figure that out